# Javascript default arguments, only passing the second

Tags: javascript

Currently, I have a function defined like:

```
function a(b,c) {
 if (typeof(b) === "undefined") { b = 1; }
 if (typeof(c) === "undefined") { c = 2; }
 ...
}
```

Before, it set to default if the value was falsy. Changing this breaks the following call:

```
a(null, 3);
```

There is no undefined object. How can I pass only the second argument?

> There is, actually, an undefined object:

There may be an undefined object normally, but clearly in my environment something has gone awry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good test for checking the existence of a variable is this:

```
(typeof b === "undefined" || b === null)
```

Thus, your function can be rewritten like this :

```
function a(b,c) {
   if (typeof(b) === "undefined" || b === null) { b = 1; }
   if (typeof(c) === "undefined" || b === null) { c = 2; }
   ...
}
```

This would account for any of `undefined`, `null` or `void 0` passed as arguments. If you find that repetitive, you can always define a utility function :

```
function exists(obj) {
    return typeof(obj) === "undefined" || obj === null;
}
```

And this precise test is what [Coffee-script](http://coffeescript.org) does with its existential operator `?`. Coffee-script offers default arguments as well, which would make your life even easier.

Answer (score 4):

There is, actually, an `undefined` object:

```
a(undefined, 3);
```

It, is, however, for some reason, a variable, so someone *could* do :

```
undefined = 2;
```

Your code wouldn't work any more. If you want to protect yourself against someone redefining `undefined`, you can do this:

```
a(void 0 /* zero's not special; any value will do */, 3);
```

The `void` prefix operator takes a value, discards it, and returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you say there's no undefined...

```
a(undefined, 3)
```

is what you want